# How to loop $_POST in PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently creating a simplistic pre-order system. The user places a pre-order and their order gets inserted into the `pre_orders` table with a hash and the `cc` table is updated with the same hash.

I have added a form in the admin panel where an administrator can release all of the pre-ordered digital items to all buyers on release day. I would like the form to check if the hash from `pre_orders` matches a hash in `cc`, if it does then that record is updated and `approved` is set to `1` if not then it will just skip and go onto the next one to check. I see I need some kind of loop but not sure where to start.

```
if(isset($_POST['release'])){
        $stmtt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM `pre_orders`");
        $stmtt -> execute(array($_SESSION['user_session']));
        $hashh = $stmtt -> fetch();
        $hash = $hashh['hash'];

        $stmttttt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `cc` WHERE `hash` = :hash");
        $stmttttt -> execute(array(':hash' => $hash));
        $count = $stmttttt -> fetch();

        $stmttt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM `cc` WHERE `hash` = :hash");
        $stmttt -> execute(array(':hash' => $hash));
        $check = $stmttt -> fetch();
        $idd = $check['id'];

        if($count == true){     

        $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("UPDATE `cc` SET `approved` = 1 WHERE `id` = :id"); //remove `approved` at end of pre order period
        $stmt -> execute(array(':id' => $idd));
        $success = "Pre-orders released successfully.";

        } else {
            $error = "error";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this in a single update statement:

```
UPDATE cc AS c
INNER JOIN pre_orders AS p ON p.hash = c.hash
SET c.approved = 1
WHERE c.approved <> 1
```

The Inner join will only find rows that have a pre-order and cc row with matching hash.  The WHERE clause is just a little extra embellishment in case you want to look at "affected rows" to determine how many new orders were updated.  Hopefully you default the cc.approved value to 0 rather than NULL.

If you allow cc.approved to be NULL, you would need the WHERE clause to be

```
WHERE c.approved IS NULL OR c.approved <> 1
```

The specific technique you would need depends on which client library you're using in PHP (mysqli or PDO).

Comment: This is correct.  Although, you may want to first just run the select so you can get a list of emails/users/etc. to send a notification that the item has been released to them and then update the table. "You pre-ordered and waited, now it is time! Click to download/access/update/whatever..."

Comment: That's a good point.  I assume that there is a separate "release" job that would do the work of going through the orders and sending them the digital item as well as alerting.

Comment: the comment was more directed to teh OP but I figured I'd attach it to the sensible answer.  it seems from his question that some users/accounts were flagged as already having it, so i figured there wouldn't be an easy way to determine who just got it vs who had it after the update was performed